# AMPPS cannot stop MySQL

Tags: mysql, xampp, ampps

I clicked the stop button in AMPPS, but it cannot stop MySQL from running. Also tried run as admin, which did not work as well.

I am running on Windows, and the stop button used to work.
Now, I have to run the following command to stop the server.
"mysqladmin -u root  shutdown"

Answer (score 2):

Did you change the root password?

Comment: Yes I did, but I also change the [client] password field from 'mysql' to empty.

Comment: FYI, I had this problem too after changing the default MySQL password installed with AMPPS, and updating the "[client] password" to the new password resolved the issue.

Comment: @musicliftsme and kindly how did you updated the client password? Thanks

Comment: You can edit the [client] password thusly: go to your Ampps folder / mysql / my.ini and edit the default password to your new root password.